# Gremlin: Return result count along with results

Tags: titan, gremlin

I'm trying to return a partial set of results using `range()`for pagination in my app. I need to also return the total number of records in the overall result as part of the response. A response should look like:

```
{
  postcount: 239,
  posts: [
    {
      postID: 1,
      postTitle:'First post'
    },
    {
      postID: 2,
      postTitle:'Second post'
    },
    {
      postID: 3,
      postTitle:'Third post'
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been trying to make something like this work with no luck:

`g.V().hasLabel('post').as('postcount','posts').select('postcount','posts').by(__.count()).by(__.range(0,2).valueMap())`

That appends a `postcount = 1` property to each item. How do I adjust this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found on the [Gremlin-Users list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/OPXuzkQJxyA/g7x6iCrwDQAJ) per Daniel Kuppitz:

> In 3.2.0:

```
> g.V().hasLabel("person").fold().project("users","userCount").by(range(local,
> 0, 2)).by(count(local))
```

> Prior 3.2.0:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").fold().as("users","userCount").select("users","userCount").by(range(local,
> 0, 2)).by(count(local))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could break it up into two queries:

```
pCount = g.V().hasLabel("post").count().next();
pList = g.V().hasLabel("post").range(0,2).valueMap().toList();
map = ["postcount": pCount, "posts": pList]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `union` step to achieve what you want to do. Example:

```
 g.V().hasLabel("post").union(
               __.select("postcount").by(__.count()), // postcount property
               __.range(0,2).valueMap() // your range
            ) //end of union
```

For more info, check [docs](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#union-step)

Comment: `Union` seems like the right approach but I'm still struggling with the syntax. I tried your example but got 'The traversal strategies are complete and the traversal can no longer be modulated'. I also tried the following: `g.V().hasLabel("post").as("postcount","post").union(select("postcount").by(__.count()),select("post").by(__.range(0,2).valueMap()))` but it returns post, count = 1, post, count = 1 every line.

Comment: Ah, your example is missing a `_` before `.count()`. However it just outputs all my posts without regard to `range` and does not include a count. Not sure why this doesn't work, because I follow the thought process and it seems like it should. I'm running this in the console if it matters.